# How to Open php.ini file from cPanel or WHM

Tags: php, configuration

Recently I have purchased a VPS and I have the root access. I need to enable the `extension=php_mysqli.dll` in php.ini. But I could not find the php.ini file. Actually I am a Windows User and I do not know how to use Linux or SSH Commands. I want to find php.ini file and open it manually and make my desired changes. Can Any one help me?

Answer (score 1):

Edit, on a cPanel server you should not be editing the PHP.ini file to enable extensions like that.

Within WHM, locate EasyApache and go through the guided setup for Apache and PHP.  In the 'Exhaustive Options' screen, you'll find a checkbox to enable the mysqli extension.

Enable all the extensions you need, then hit 'Save and Build'.  This will rebuild Apache and PHP using the configuration you just selected.

Comment: to run this command `find /etc/ -type f -name php.ini` Where Do I need to go in my cPanel or WHM. I mean which Option I need to use? Actually I have never run the commands before.

Comment: To run commands like this, you will need to connect over SSH.  I will edit my answer on how to edit PHP.ini in cPanel.